# Callback on transaction or commit()

Tags: ember-data

How can I achieve something similar like that?

```
App.saveManyDifferentModels()

App.store.commit(function() {
    $("#spinner.gif").hide()
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no generic hook at that moment on the transaction that would allow that.

However, if you are persisting a single record, you could add use the `didCreate` or `didUpdate` hook on the model.

Another option could be to handle that while changing state/route on the app.

Comment: Let's hope that will be easier using the upcoming `BasicAdapter`!

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to do this.  For example in your controller you can add a 'didUpdate' method to your model, like this:

```
var post = this.get("model");

post.didUpdate = function() {
    $("#spinner.gif").hide();
};

this.get("store").commit();
```

Comment: Where is the difference between the solution above?

Comment: Because I have an actual example of it... :)